# Webview content not resizing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a webview.. with the following attributes:

1.scalesPageToFit

2.Autoresizing masks

3.contentmode = aspectFit

After loading it fits to the page as obvious. But as soon as i zoom in and then zoom out to normal; rotating the device doesn't fit completely.

As a tweak, i have checked if the orientation mode is landscape reload the web page. I read various posts in this regard, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I have answered your question. Kindly Check it

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 folowing options:

Add this into head section of your html file:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Or call [myWebView reload] when orientation changes

Comment: Prince,
As of now i am reloading the page, but that too appears flickery. Like  it is first appears break and then reloads. Also, i am looking for a very good solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Code

```
NSString *website =@"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:website];
NSURLRequest *requestURL =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

mywebview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
mywebview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;    

[mywebview loadRequest:requestURL];
```

Comment: Amir these are very simple lines of code & i already have done this.. Problem occurs when the page has been loaded and i started zoom in then zoom out and rotate the device to landscape.

Comment: @Tarun I have done with them. I also made Universal App using same lines. Its Work for me.

Comment: Amir, normally the webview is working fine. Let me clarify the steps/sequences regarding the issue:

Comment: Actually it is resizing correctly in both mode if you don't have pinched it to mininum or maximum level. But after the url has finished loading, in the portrait mode pinch it to minimum level and then rotate the device You will observe that frames come correct but the content is still the same as it was in Portrait mode. 
If you are pointing towards the same issue, kindly share a sample snippet.

Comment: @Tarun you can reload on rotating the view? what you say about it??

Comment: Amir, this is already resolved. In fact, i found that safari app behaves same most of the time. So i have applied a fix that almost working gud for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Tarun can you please provide me the code? I also need it. I want a wordpress app to be open in my native app.

Answer (score 0):

It took more than 2 days to find out the reason causing this issue. Actually webview was working correctly except the fact that if you try to use PinchGesture to zoom out further.. webview will baheve in the same way.

To overcome this issue, we need to set the zoom scale of scroll view in Webview under willRotate method. However, it's animating weirdly but one can make a guess where the issue lies.